# Runtime 429 ActiveX component error occurs when Access calls an open Outlook

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

I have VBA code in MS Access applications which create emails.  The relevant code lines are:

```
Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
Dim objOutlookMsg As Outlook.MailItem

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Set objOutlookMsg = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

'...
'code in here to set the "To" address, subject and body
'...

 objOutlookMsg.Display
```

This code worked for the past two decades, give or take. A couple months ago, about 10 users out of more than 100 can no longer generate emails from my applications.  Here is the error that they get:

> Error #429: "ActiveX component can't create object."

We thought the problem might be permissions related since our IT staff were playing with UAC (User Account Control) at the time.  The IT staff reverted all the UAC changes and the email generation problem persists with those 10 or so staff.

There was a Windows update about the time this problem started, so the problem may be related to how MS Access interacts with Windows and/or Outlook.

Some factors to note:

1. If Outlook is closed the code runs *without* error.  It is only when Outlook is already open that it fails.
2. We tried re-building profiles, changing PCs and even changing operating systems and versions of Office.  We have also tried elevating permissions under which my applications run.  Sometimes one of these steps seems to fix the problem and other times it does not.
3. Most of our staff use Windows 7 and Office 2010, but we are in the process of upgrading to Windows 10 and Office 365.  Some staff with the upgrade also have the email problem.  And some do not.
4. I looked at the version and build number of Office 365 on a machine that works compared to a machine that gives the error.  The build and version numbers are the same.  (Version 1906.  Build 11727.20244)
5. All machines in question are 64 bit (at least, that's what I've been told)
6. Before releasing applications to staff, I create a .accde version of the file and then rename the extension to .accdr so that staff are running the file in runtime mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on (1) (works as expected when Outlook is not running), the problem is that Outlook and your script are running under different security contexts.
Make sure that either neither app or both are running under elevated privileges (Run As Administrator).

Comment: Thanks for your reply Dmitry!  I'm going to ask our help desk/Active Directory staff to look into this.  I'm wondering though if this cause makes sense since some staff can run the same code and some can't?  I think we set up computers the same for staff...?  How likely is it that some staff have different Outlook permissions vs app permissions?  I'll look into it.  Just seeing if you still think this could be the issue.  Thanks again.

Comment: It does not have to be Outlook - are you sure Access (where your script is executed) is not running with elevated privileges?

Comment: Dmitry:  You rock!  Your answer was the clue that we needed.  The Access app *is* running with elevated permissions thru the elevated starting batch file.  Apparently Outlook permissions needed to be elevated to match.  That was the answer, says our permissions person.  I'll mark your reply as the answer.  I just wanted to give you details and heart-felt THANKS.